# How to use scopes in controller and views: Filter table by categories (enum) using scopes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, filtering, scopes

I have an html table in my rails app where I sholl all my expenses. Expenses are an enum, which can take values like "education", "beer", "bliblablub".

I would like to be able to filter my html table according to these enum values. I have links on the side of the table on which the user can click. Now I want the table to filter the results according to the links.

Now, I think scopes are the way to go here, but I'm having a hard time understanding how they really work. I created a scope like this just to understand it:

`scope :find_category, -> {Expense.where(category:"education")}`

In the Rails console this works, and when I call the find_category method it gives me the instances with education.

I think a dynamic scope then would be something like:

`scope :find_category, -> (category) {Expense.where(category:category)}`

So far so good. Now, what I don't really get is how I can use the filtered result now in my controller and view, that is to say how to filter it when clicking on the link.

I tried this:

controller (trying to get my queried results)

```
  def find_category
    @expense = Expense.find_category
    render action: :index
  end
```

And then put a route for find_categories:

```
  resources :expenses, path: 'expenses' do
    collection do
      get :find_category
    end
  end
```

and put a link in the index:

```
 <%= link_to 'education', {controller: 'expenses', action: 'index', :find_category => 'education'}  %>
```

I know this is not really the way. Clicking on the link though it gives me `expenses?find_category=education`. Yet nothing changes. So I struggle to find the right way to do it. Of course it would also be awesome to do that without page reload, so I guess I have to use an AJAX call and JavaScript. But also with page reload would help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

When using enum, Rails creates the methods for you, so you can call directly the category, for example `Expense.education`.

Here is an example of how to manage it, **pretty raw**, assuming you are using standard Rails conventions. No special routing required.

---

Define a constant containing the categories, for example in **concerns**:

```
# model/concerns/expenses_stuff.rb
module ExpensesStuff
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  CATEGORIES = {category_a: 0, category_b: 100, category_c: 200 }

  module ClassMethods
   # class methods here
  end

  # instance methods here

end
```

---

In **models**, include the module in Expense class and define the category field as enum, picking up the constant:

```
# models/expense.rb
class Expense < ApplicationRecord
  include ExpensesStuff
  enum category: MaterialStuff::CATEGORIES
  # usual stuff
end
```

---

Now in **controller**. Take care to accept the filter value only if included in `MaterialStuff::CATEGORIES.keys`.

```
# expenses_controller.rb
class ExpensesController < ApplicationController
# usual stuff
  def index
    @expenses = filtered_expenses
  end

 private
  def sanitized_category_filter
    category = params[:category].to_sym if params[:category]
    return category.to_sym if MaterialStuff::CATEGORIES.keys.include? category
    :all
  end

  def filtered_espenses
    Expense.public_send(sanitized_category_filter) # call directly the method
  end

end
```

---

Finally in **view** you can add your filtering links.

```
# views/expenses/index.html.erb

<style>.bg-yellow {background-color:yellow;}</style> <!-- Move to *.css -->
<% def active_filter(category); 'bg-yellow' if category.to_s == params[:category]; end # move to helpers %>

<% (ExpensesStuff::CATEGORIES.keys << :all).each do |category| %>
  <%= link_to category, expenses_path(category: category), class: active_filter(category) %> |
<% end %>
```

You are now able to add new categories just updating the `CATEGORIES` Hash. You can also use it in the form as options for select.

Comment: what a great answer, thank you my friend. Sorry for the late reply, I was taking some time off. I will try to implement this this week and will comment/accept etc...